# Can we display parent object details in child object's page layout?

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

I need to display parent object details on a child object's page layout once it creating.Not after creating. And we need to do this without creating a visual force page. Can you please let me know is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently formula fields cannot displayed on the standard page layout when editing a new or existing record.
So this isn't possible assuming you want to display the parent fields as formulas on your child record.